# Arabic language not working

Tags: android

I have a list of 114 items and this list contains both Arabic and English words but the problem is the Arabic words is not properly showing, it is showing boxes and I have copied tahoma.ttf to my assets folder and I m using these two java classes also [FROM HERE](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper/tree/master/src/org/amr/arabic)
but the problem is that it is using only single string and I m using Array of String ,so how to resolve this problem

Comment: Where are you displaying the Arabic word , in Textview or in Webview , Pls ensure u r using utf-8 encoding .

Comment: I'm displaying it in textview